# Adjective for function types on wether the values are received or sent

Tags: patterns-and-practices, generic-programming, type-theory

I don't know how to phrase this better, but I remember reading an article about type theory, that categorized the values being received by a function and the values being sent back from the functions.

The example was something like:

```
T2 function(arg T1)
```

In this example `T1` would be a *received* type, and `T2` would be a *sent* type. And the rule of thumb for engineers was "make `T1` as generic as possible, since it is *'received'*, and `T2` as specific as possible since it is *'sent'*." For example:

```
Array<int64> function(arg Iterable<Number>)
```

The goal is for the caller to use any type they want but fits the function, and use all the available methods from the returned value.

It was getting trickier with callbacks, for example, in the case of:

```
T3 function2(callback Callback<T1, T2>)  # Callback takes T1 and returns T2
```

`T1` is the *sent* type, and `T2` was the type *received*. So `T1` should be as specific as possible, while `T2` should be as generic as possible.

The reasoning behind it was that `T1` is "generated" by the `function2`, while T2 is "passed" to `function2`.

I know that there is a "scientific" name on whether the value of the type is "sent" or "received" by the function, but I can't find it.

Comment: You're just looking for the common terminology, right?  If so, it'd be "_return type_" (which is the type of the returned value) and "_parameter type_" (for the type of a parameter/argument).

Comment: If you want to talk to programmers rather than mathematicians, I'd use "parameter type" and "return type".

Answer (score 1):

The set of valid inputs to a mathematical function is the domain, and the valid outputs the codomain or range. These should more or less equate to the values contrained by the types of your sent/received nomencleture with the possible caveat that there might be values you don't want to consider as part of the domain even if the type says they are (e.g. null, depending on language) and the codmain could easily be a small subset of the output type.

I'd also be wary about using these terms on something that wasn't at least approaching a function in the mathematical sense (ideally a pure, total function). As indicated in the comments for normally progammery code argument type/return type are probably better

Answer (score -1):

An input type to a function is *contravariant*, whilst a return type is *covariant*; see, for example, the [Wikipedia article on covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types) (particularly for function types).

Comment: "Variance refers to how subtyping between more complex types relates to subtyping between their components" - this is not the case here

Comment: Did you read the section on [function types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types)? It's describing exactly the situation asked for in the original question.

Comment: It is about whether one function type is convertible to another.

Comment: The wording in the question "`T1` as generic as possible" is equivalent to asking that `T1` should be a superclass of anything on which the function should be called. Picking types that are generic or specific only makes sense in a language in which there is a notion of subtype (even if it's not explicit). A type `A` is "convertible" to a type `B` if `A` is a subclass of `B`. The language may not be the same, but the concepts are.

Comment: "X is contravariant with respect to Y" means that more specific versions of X must have less specific versions of Y (or the other way around - not sure). But in this case we are not talking about more or less specific versions of X.

Comment: The question asks about making some types more or less specific: "make `T1` as generic as possible, since it is 'received', and `T2` as specific as possible since it is 'sent'." corresponds to "`T1` is contravariant and `T2` is covariant". Perhaps the question is asking for a more general situation, such as the [Robustness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle)?